# NotSerializableException thrown by Grails application running on Tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am using tomcat6 running on Ubuntu server. I have deployed three Grails 1.3.7 applications. All of these applications are using a plugin which contains my domain classes.

I am getting this exception after tomcat6 is restarted. Any ideas what's causing IOException? I could try to implement Serializable interface in my Groovy domain class... but I think that is not really needed.

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.User
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.User
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.readObject(ListenerMethod.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:964)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.readObject(ListenerMethod.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.Hashtable.readObject(Hashtable.java:859)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1029)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1475)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

This is how User class looks like:

```
class User {
    String name
    Profile profile
    static belongsTo = [profile : Profile] 
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, you're storing an instance of User in an HttpSession object. And Tomcat is configured to store the sessions on disk (that way, sessions can survive a server restart). Possible solutions:

1. Tell Tomcat [not to persist the sessions.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)
2. Make sure that User (and all its members) implement Serializable. (This is probably what you want.)
3. Don't store the User in the session object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should mark `User` as implementing Serializable.  I don't see any reason not to.  You'd just need to make sure that `Profile` is also Serializable.

There may not be an immediate need for this is a simple web server / application.  But if the server ever needs to save the session state outside of running memory (into a database, or between clustered servers, for example) - everything put into the Session must be serializable.